# Compile Typescript using Const variable

Tags: typescript

I declare a variable named `ver` I want to make typescript compile my code like this:

```
const ver = '1.0';
var url = `/images/logo.jpg?ver=${ver}`
```

now result is:

```
var ver = '1.0';
var url = "/images/logo.jpg?ver=" + ver;
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
var url = "/images/logo.jpg?ver=1.0";
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you want this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't do any inlining of constants, except for `const enum`s (and that would still leave you with a string concatenation).  You could file a suggestion, but I'm guessing it would be considered out of scope of [TypeScript's goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals).