# Why Typesript compiler change a const into a var?

Tags: typescript, constants

In consts.ts i have

```
const s1: string = 'test';
```

I compile it with tsc consts.ts and then in consts.js it became

```
var s1 = 'test';
```

Why?

Comment: can you please add your tsconfig content to the question?

Comment: @Oro Hi, it's a fresh new install of typescript with npm install typescript --save-dev.

Comment: did you run the init command for generating tsconfg file?

Comment: @Oro No, I only followed what's in TS install guide at https://www.typescriptlang.org/download

Comment: I left an answer below on how to create tsconfig file for your project, let me know if something is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems that you don't have any typescript configuration for your project. You have to run

```
npx tsc --init
```

and then you will be able to change the target value for compiler option there

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wonder why is this not mentioned in their official installation guide. Anyway, I did this and it generated a tsconfig.json but my const is still being compiled into a var...

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it out. You can change that behavior by changing the target value. You can see allowed values in doc https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target

Comment: Even with "target": "es2017" it will still change const into a var.

Comment: @Eddi It sounds like you are launching the TS compiler in a place that doesn't see your tsconfig.json file.  It is definitely true that [ES3 target turns `const` into `var`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAjEA) while [ES2017 preserves `const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAjEA).  If you're not seeing that then you are probably not actually changing the target.

Comment: @Oro Oh yeah you are right. I try tsc -t ES2017 consts.ts and it work. The config file has no effect which I already created it with npx tsc --init and I can see the file is there.

Comment: @Eddi You have to also configure rootDir and outDir in the config file.

Comment: If you invoke `tsc` without any input files, then it will search for a `tsconfig.json` in the current directory. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Answer (score 9):

TypeScript compiles to ECMAScript 3 code unless you specify otherwise [[doc link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target)], and ECMAScript didn't introduce `const` until version 6.

Comment: @ruakh TY for this good point. I take that back. https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/are-let-and-const-faster-than-var-in-javascript-2d0b7f22a66#:~:text=The%20reason%20const%20is,the%20lack%20there%2Dof).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have"target": "es2016" in my tsconfig.json it still compile const into a var.

Comment: @Eddi it is kinda feeling like TS doesn't do this. I just set the target as well, and I'm not seeing any `const` in my dist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236950/compile-typescript-using-const-variable. Ultimately, I'm happy w/ it, because TS is enforcing that at compile time. You can't generate output (can you?) with a constraint TS is complaining about. You're looking at the wrong layer

Comment: It's my first time trying typescript, it doesn't made sense to me changing my  constant into a variable...

Comment: @Eddi If you're using namespaces, TypeScript compiler always compiles `let`/`const` to `var`. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16256#issuecomment-306244683

Answer (score 3):

I did what @Oro says, but still get `var`, until i change my command from `npx tsc xxx.ts` / `tsc xxx.ts` to `npx tsc`, then I get `const` :)

Comment: All the above didn't work for me, but this one did the trick. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Change ECMAScript Module in compilerOptions object in tsconfig.json file to Recent Module.

```
"compilerOptions": {    
"target": "es2022"
}
```